# Listview Implement onItemClick with Swipe to dismiss

Tags: android, android-listview

I am using the listview animations library by nhaarman https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations to implement animations and swipe to dismiss functionality.

However I also need to implement OnItemClickListener for my list view items but the swipe to dismiss functionality wont let the items respond to onclick event. 
I have setting the android:clickable property in the list item layout but it made no difference.